# this.http.post doesn't not send params in angular 4

Tags: php, angular, typescript, post

I need to create a login system, I try to send the params to the PHP server.

Angular app

```
return this.http.post<any>('/s/login/index.php', {
                username: username,
                password: password
            }).map(user => {
                console.log(username); 
                // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
                if (user) {
                    // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                }

                return user;
            });
    }
```

PHP server

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

 // Check if username is empty
if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
    $username_err = 'Please enter username.';
    $resp->body->message=$username_err;
    $resp=json_encode($resp);
    echo $resp;
}
```

But the server always returns

```
{status: "400", body: {message: "Please enter username."}}
```

Comment: Did you try including params like they did at  https://angular.io/guide/http#url-parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is because you are not setting headers.**

first import necessary modules

```
import {HttpClient,HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {URLSearchParams} from '@angular/http';
```

try it this way.

```
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
let options = {
    headers: headers
};

let body = new URLSearchParams();
body.set('username', username);
body.set('password', password);

return this.http.post<any>('/s/login/index.php', body, options).map(user => {
            console.log(username); 
            // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
            if (user) {
                // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
            }

            return user;
        });
}
```

---

Tell me if it does not work. I am here !

Comment: Now appears ERROR in src/app/_services/authentication.service.ts(20,15): error TS2345: Argument of type 'RequestOptions' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.
  Types of property 'headers' are incompatible.
    Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type 'HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
      Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type '{ [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
        Index signature is missing in type 'Headers'.

Comment: And it continues to show {status: "400", body: {message: "Please enter username."}}

Comment: Can you see the request sent from your browser developer tools on the network tab ? 
Is the request sent with proper parameters there ?

Comment: I can see because I write a console in LoginComponent

Comment: login() {
        this.loading = true;
        this.authenticationService.login(this.model.username, this.model.password)
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                    console.log(data);
                    this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
                },
                error => {
                    this.alertService.error(error);
                    this.loading = false;
                });
    }

Comment: No I am saying check what kind of request are you sending to the php backend from the network tab.

Or var_dump($_POST) and see what is the request you are sending.